# bottom border width for text

Tags: css, underline

I have some text which I want underlined.  Now, I don't just want the actual text to underline, I want the line to stretch across the screen.

I do:

```
H4{align:left; font-style: bold; border-bottom: 1px black solid;}
```

However, I don't want the line to run the entire width of the screen. I only want it to be say 750px wide or a percentage of the screen.  I try:

```
H4{align:left; font-style: bold; border-bottom: 1px black solid; width:750px;}
```

But this does not work. The line still runs the entire width of the page. Any tips?

Comment: How exactly does it not work? What happens?

Comment: The sample you have specified should work as you expect. What is the result?

Comment: It is working http://jsfiddle.net/enve/Pu2QJ/

Comment: please post a jsfiddle showing it not working, so we can see your html structure too

Comment: This is working... http://jsfiddle.net/pvjvA/

Comment: The second CSS code is working http://jsfiddle.net/enve/Pu2QJ

Comment: I have asked for this to be deleted because I made a mess of question

Answer (score 0):

use a `<hr />`

then in the css:

```
hr{
    width: 75%;
    border: solid #DDD;
    border-width: 1px 0 0;
    clear: both;
    margin: 10px 0 30px;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have some other CSS that is overriding your definition. For example, your CSS does function as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/pvjvA/1/

```
h4 {
  text-align:left; 
  font-style: bold; 
  border-bottom: 1px black solid; 
  width:750px;
}
```

Comment: Just curious -- do you actually do this in practice? (Set a width on a header tag?) It feels odd to me. Maybe only because I don't usually do it.

Comment: Yes, if the template requires it.